# reset value when using react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select

I am using [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/home) for my select dropdown. The issue I am having is that there is no empty option to reset the dropdown value if the user changes their mind.

Currently I am taking the options and manually adding an empty string, but I feel there must be something already in the library to handle this? I cannot find anything in the docs.

My code looks like the below, and there is a [code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-wilson-0ht3z).

import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

```
const App = () => {
  const options = [
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ];

  return <Dropdown options={options} />;
}

const Dropdown = ({ options }) => {
  const optionsWithEmptyOption = [{ value: "", label: "" }, ...options];
  return <Select options={optionsWithEmptyOption} />;
};
```

Comment: Ideally, make your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: What lots of people do isn't necessarily correct. There are two problems with off-site examples: 1. People have to go off-site to use them. 2. It makes it **really, really easy** to accidentally leave out important code/markup/config from your question, making the question useless if the external link goes away.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the blue line is what I added with this line `const optionsWithEmptyOption = [{ value: "", label: "" }, ...options];` This doesn't come from out of the box, but I feel there must be something as I would see this as being a valid use case

Comment: For some reason I assumed you hadn't included that in the example, so the problem was demonstrated. Just wasn't paying enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

Plase check this out

https://codesandbox.io/s/zow1c?module=/example.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
import { colourOptions } from './docs/data';

export default class CreatableSingle extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Input Changed');
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, I see, if the `x` is there like that, it is clearable. In the design I am working with there is no `x`

Comment: Anyway, the user has to perform some action to deselect selected value

Answer (score 0):

### Empty Unicode

I add line to options, and write between the apostrophes empty unicode like this: ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ .. you can mark it but dont see it.

```
const options = [
    { value: "", label: "⠀" },
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ];
```

And I change this:

```
return <Select options={options} />;
```

Comment: that's what I am already doing ‍♂️. `const optionsWithEmptyOption = [{ value: "", label: "" }, ...options];`

Comment: Ok so I didn't understand you, are you looking for something like Sandeep Patel answer?

Answer (score 0):

what about `const optionsWithEmptyOption = [{ value: null, label: "Select..." }, ...options];`

I'm not really good with explanations, but @NicoHaase is right, so here it goes...

as far as I know, you must give a value to value `null` (if nothing) or `string` ... same for the `label`, #1 because of the user UX and second so react-select knows what to display. But if you really need to leave it in black, and you can try to modify in the styles, in order to have the same `height` as the other options.

Comment: Yeah, what about that? Does this resolve the given problem? Then please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it